# Apps break after they are moved to SD card

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, app2sd

I am running a custom ROM (so it might be that). I have write permissions. But when I move apps to SD card after a reboot they are gone. Going to the app manager a toast appears  "App isn't anvalible" (I know I spelled that wrong). What is my problem here exactly , and if you know can you help me out?

Comment: Which custom ROM and specific build of it are you running?

Comment: @Firelord Sorry for late reply . I am running CM 12.1 (made by Thinkers Dev BD) for the Walton Primo H3. It's still in beta though. (Beta 4)

Answer (score -1):

The ROM had issues, so there's another way around it.
Root the device, make a second logical partition on your SD card,and install Link2SD.
Also don't forget to backup.